# Error when converting a Lead record

Tags: picklist, record-type, lead-conversion, field-mapping

When converting a Lead record the following error message is displayed:

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: Somerfield: [Store__c]`

The issue happens only when I'm logged in with one of my user account and then converting a Lead to an Account/Contact/Opportunity.

If I'm logged in as system administrator I can convert the Lead successfully.

I've checked `Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set` which is enabled.

I've checked the field mapping between the Lead and the Account. All properly set.

I also checked the list in the Account record type. All properly set.

Please advise what can be the reason of such issue and how to allow my users to make successful convert?

Comment: If you uncheck "Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set" does it work when logged in via a user account?

Comment: @ZackWalton I cannot uncheck the  `Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set`. The system does not allow it.

Comment: @ZackWalton The issues happens only when I convert the Lead record whiled I'm logged in with particular user. Only then I receive the following error message: `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: Somerfield: [Store__c]`

Comment: @ZackWalton Once I change the ownership of the Lead record to myself I can convert the Lead records successfully.

Comment: @ZackWalton I'll strongly appreciate if you can advise what else I can try to be able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by changing the default record type setting in the user profile.